# use queries from program or use stored procedure for inserting/update/delete data in database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to ask that which is a better way to insert/update/delete data in to database, to use queries directly from data-layer or create stored procedure for every inserting and deletion?

Comment: you can find pros & cons of Stored Procedure v/s Inline Query...

Comment: In my opinion the best method is procedure.

Comment: if my requirements are to create some tables dynamically too, what should I do for those tables?

Comment: Either use a stored procedure to create the tables, or decide that you'll have NO program logic (beyond defaults and cross-table relations) in your database, and let it all be queries program-side.

Answer (score 1):

Your question depends **entirely** on the type of queries you're talking about.

- For simple CRUD operations on a single table with no database-side rules that need to be followed, direct `SELECT`, `UPDATE`, or `DELETE` statements are fine.
- For more complex operations, such as when your database applies normalization and access multiple tables, a stored procedure is worth the work.  (In fact, "use stored procedures only when they're worth the extra work" is a good rule.)
- For simple CRUD for multiple rows in a single query call, a program query is the only way to go unless you want to muck about with XML.
- (And for simple CRUD where you're going to be using a recordset-aware interface, either should work just fine.)

Comment: There's also a difference from the security standpoint. In SQL Server, you can put an `INSERT INTO A` statement into a stored procedure and grant a user the EXECUTE right on that SP only, the INSERT right on `A` would not be required in that situation. Without the INSERT right, the user would then be able to insert into `A` only using that SP. Invoking an arbitrary `INSERT INTO A ...` would be prohibited.

Answer (score 0):

i always used a Stored procedure to do simple CRUD operation

i used to do all CRUD operation within one SP, hope it will help.

**For Example**

```
create proc <procedure name>
(
  <parameterName> <datatype>=<default value if any>,
  @mode varchar(20)
)
as
begin

 if(@mode='Insert')
 begin

    --your query for insert
 end

 if(@mode='Update')
 begin

    --your query for update
 end

 if(@mode='Delete')
 begin

    --your query for delete
 end

 if(@mode='Select')
 begin

    --your query for Select
 end

end
```

you can have more "Mode" like 'select by id','soft delete','hard delete',etc...